# When is the Thom class the Poincare dual of the zero section?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

As the title suggests, when is the Thom class the Poincare dual of the zero section? For starters, it's true for the normal bundle of an immersion...

Comment: If you represent cohomology classes by proper maps from manifolds (e.g. as in Quillen's "Elementary proofs of some results in cobordism theory using Steenrod operations") then there is a certain sense in which this is always true.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know exactly what you are asking (Thom class of what? Poincare duality in what manifold?), but here is an answer to some question in this family:

If $E\to M$ is a smooth oriented vector bundle of rank $r$ on a compact smooth manifold of dimension $m$, then the Thom class of the bundle can be regarded as an element of $H^r(D(E),S(E))$ where $D(E)$ is the disk bundle and $S(E)=\partial D(E)$ is the sphere bundle. This corresponds by the Poincare duality isomorphism to the element $H_{m}(D(E))$ given by the submanifold $M\subset D(E)$ (the zero section or any other section).

This can be generalized to the case where $M$ is noncompact, or has nonempty boundary. For example, in the former case the duality isomorphism goes from $H^r(D(E),S(E))$ to the locally finite homology group $H_{m}^{lf}(D(E))$, in which there is a class given by the noncompact manifold $M$.

It can also be generalized to unoriented situations, but here the homology and cohomology groups involve nontrivial coefficient systems in general.

Answer (score 1):

For De Rham cohomology, this is always true. It is theorem 6.24 in Bott and Tu.